# why the avro generated java code has so many deprecated fileds

Tags: avro

I am using avro-maven-plugin 1.8.1 to generate java code from schema,and all the fields are public and deprecated,like this:

```
  public class data_elements extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2829359487251568000L;
  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("......");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence timestamp;
  @Deprecated public double value;
  @Deprecated public java.lang.CharSequence op;
...
}
```

It makes confused and uncomfortable, does anyone know why it is like that?

Answer (score 4):

If you pass in the `fieldVisibility=private` parameter then the `@Deprecated` should disappear and your fields will be private.

Comment: For cases where you treat POJO as beans, wouldn't accessing the native types be faster than accessing the boxed types via the public getters?

Comment: It is not working. I have these, <configuration>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro/</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/</outputDirectory>
        <fieldVisibility>PRIVATE</fieldVisibility>
       </configuration>